# Apontar para diferente diretório no .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Alguém sabe se existe alguma maneira de com o `RewriteRule`, poder apontar para um caminho, que está em pastas atrás de onde eu tenho o meu `htaccess`.

Por exemplo

```
RewriteRule ^cena.js$ ../../../pasta/pasta2/file.php [L]
```

Este código não funciona visto que `.htaccess` não gosta daquele caminho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar `../../../` não vai funcionar mesmo, pois o .htaccess trabalha a partir do diretório "Base" ou que você definiu como "Base".

Por padrão a Base é o proprio local que o .htaccess esta localizado e no caso o que pode lhe ajudar é usar `RewriteBase` para configurar a nova "Base", note que o caminho definindo nele deve ser absoluto, por exemplo, supondo que `pasta/pasta2` esteja na raiz do apache, mas o .htaccess esteja na pasta `/etc/www/projeto1/admin/dashboard/pasta/pasta2`, então você deverá fazer isto:

```apacheconf
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cena.js$ pasta/pasta2/file.php [L]
```

O `RewriteBase /` vai levar a raiz do Apache, no caso `/etc/www`, note que todas regras do `mod_rewrite` irão sempre iniciar do `/etc/www/`, então você sempre irá funciona a partir da nova "Base".

Answer (score 1):

Um motivo lógico para não estar funcionando, caso o caminho esteja correto, é o arquivo estar fora da pasta pública definida em [DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html).

Exemplo, se o `DocumentRoot` do site estiver em `/site/public/html/`, não conseguirá acessar um arquivo acima desse diretório pelo *rewrite rule* do `htaccess`, exemplo: `/site/public/arquivo.php`.

É acessível pelo PHP usando `include()`, por exemplo, e obviamente deve também ter as permissões de acesso cedidas ao Apache e PHP. Tais configurações são definidas pelo [Sistema Operacional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_operativo).